# Transformar un índice con dos elementos de una serie en dos columnas de una dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Quiero transfromar un Series `s` cual index es un array con dos elementos (el titulo y un partido espesifico para cada indice) en una dataframe con tres columnas (`titulo`, `data`, `partido`). Es por decir transformar

```
[truc19, GK]    -0.074581
[truc19, UNA]    0.135000
[truc20, GK]    -0.549393
[truc20, UNA]    0.087734
...
```

en :

```
truc19     truc20    party
-0.074581  0.135000  GK
-0.549393  0.087734  UNA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crear ejemplo:

```sql
import pandas as pd

x = [[['truc19', 'GK'], -0.074581],
     [['truc19', 'UNA'], 0.135000],
     [['truc20', 'GK'], -0.549393],
     [['truc20', 'UNA'], 0.087734]]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['título', 'partido'])
```

Transformar dataframe:

```
df['truc'] = df['título'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['party'] = df['título'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df = df.drop('título', axis=1)

df = df.pivot(index='party', columns='truc', values='partido')

print(df)
```

```
truc     truc19    truc20
party                    
GK    -0.074581 -0.549393
UNA    0.135000  0.087734
```